# Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from etc

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc

I have a little jsp site with a mysql DB (both hosted by a provider).

From time to time i get this error when i try to connection to the DB.

```
Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 441,197
milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 26    
milliseconds ago.
```

I read several posts on the internet talking about similar problem, i but no one seems to suits my issue. Mine is a very simple site, maybe i should set some attributes in the context.xml file. I Created a context.xml similar to the one shown on the book i used to study java and jsp.

Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/prova" reloadable="true"> 
     <Resource
      name="jdbc/myDataSource"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      url="..." 
      username="..."
      password="..."
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>  
</Context>
```

the way i "query" the DB is this:

```
1) i open the connection
2) i make the select
3) i close connection, statement and resultset
```

I use `mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar`

Comment: Try to add folowing attributes to the Resource element: validationQuery="SELECT 1" testOnBorrow="true"

Comment: @matteodepasquali Try to increase mysql set timeout if this does not work then with the user your are trying to access does not have access to database tables.

Comment: @Dmitry Tsechoev ill make it and ill make some tests. I'll make you know if the problem is solved

Comment: @pise i didnt unserstand the last part fo your answer.

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali I mean to say your database user may not be having access to that particular table, if so even that time you get this error.

Comment: check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985169/1066779)